# UNNEST array stored inside object?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to unnest an array which is stored inside an object in BigQuery. I am relatively inexperienced when it comes to JSON's, but I have been looking for a solution for this for a while with no luck.

I have other cases similar to this where I have created UDF's inside BigQuery to define the structure of JSON arrays and JSON objects where they are separate, but this is the first case I have come across where one is inside the other.

Example Structure (JSON name is "routes");

```
{"legs": 

        [{"eta": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "etd": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z", "change": "new"}], 

"arrival_time": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00", "cut_off_date": "2020-03-29", 
"departure_time": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00", "last_pickup_on": "2020-03-29"}
```

I have tried so many different things it would be difficult to list so I am wondering if anyone has a simple solution to this which I might have overlooked? I have read through BQ documentation and tried things like...

```
UNNEST(routes) as routes_unnest
```

Which does not work, along with stored UDF's which have a similar structure to below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `project`.udfs.extract_routes(input STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT<
    arrival_time TIMESTAMP,
    cut_off_date STRING,
    departure_time TIMESTAMP,
    last_pickup_on STRING,
    legs ARRAY<
    STRUCT<
      eta TIMESTAMP,
      etd TIMESTAMP,
      change STRING,
  LANGUAGE js AS "return JSON.parse(input);";
```

I believe my failure lies within my query, if that is the case then I am stuck with how to query the array section. Help is most appreciated here! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please show sample data from your BigQuery table? It can be a screenshot, or schema. Also, don't provide to add at least a row data to make it easier to understand the data.

Comment: Hi Sabri, the best I can do is provided above in the "Example Structure". The data is quite sensitive so a screenshot or anything else would not work. I thought the example above is sufficient?

Comment: Is the data stored as JSON in data, or is it already a BQ table with nested columns. I want to see how the data is stored, so I can help. You can show dummy data with same structure.

Comment: It is just stored as a JSON in the data. I am at the stage where I am trying to make the data inside the array "queryable" - hope this helps explain it better?

Comment: Bigquery has (very) limited support of JSON functions. I would look at changing data ingestion and load the JSON string in a table of its own as BQ would parse all nodes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
'''; 
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.arrival_time') AS arrival_time,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.cut_off_date') AS cut_off_date,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.departure_time') AS departure_time,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.last_pickup_on') AS last_pickup_on,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.eta') eta,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.etd') etd,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.change') change
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(routes, '$.legs'))) leg
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
'''; 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
SELECT '''
  {"legs": 
  [
    {"eta": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "etd": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z", "change": "new"},
    {"eta": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "etd": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z", "change": "new1"},
    {"eta": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "etd": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z", "change": "new2"}
  ], 
  "arrival_time": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00", 
  "cut_off_date": "2020-03-29", 
  "departure_time": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00", 
  "last_pickup_on": "2020-03-29"}
''' routes
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.arrival_time') AS arrival_time,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.cut_off_date') AS cut_off_date,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.departure_time') AS departure_time,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.last_pickup_on') AS last_pickup_on,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.eta') eta,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.etd') etd,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.change') change
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(routes, '$.legs'))) leg
```

with below output

```
Row arrival_time                cut_off_date    departure_time          last_pickup_on  eta etd change   
1   2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00   2020-03-29  2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00   2020-03-29  2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z    2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z    new  
2   2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00   2020-03-29  2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00   2020-03-29  2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z    2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z    new1     
3   2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00   2020-03-29  2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00   2020-03-29  2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z    2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z    new2
```

Or you can wrap-up the query with TO_JSON_STRING if you need output still as a [unnested] JSON

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
'''; 
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS route
FROM (
  SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.arrival_time') AS arrival_time,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.cut_off_date') AS cut_off_date,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.departure_time') AS departure_time,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(routes, '$.last_pickup_on') AS last_pickup_on,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.eta') eta,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.etd') etd,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(leg, '$.change') change
  FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(routes, '$.legs'))) leg
) t
```

in this case output is like below

```
Row route    
1   {"arrival_time":"2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00","cut_off_date":"2020-03-29","departure_time":"2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00","last_pickup_on":"2020-03-29","eta":"2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z","etd":"2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z","change":"new"}     
2   {"arrival_time":"2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00","cut_off_date":"2020-03-29","departure_time":"2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00","last_pickup_on":"2020-03-29","eta":"2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z","etd":"2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z","change":"new1"}    
3   {"arrival_time":"2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00","cut_off_date":"2020-03-29","departure_time":"2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00","last_pickup_on":"2020-03-29","eta":"2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z","etd":"2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z","change":"new2"}
```

Where each row is a JSON that can be easily queried further with JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR functions

```
{
"arrival_time": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000+00:00",
"cut_off_date": "2020-03-29",
"departure_time": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000+00:00",
"last_pickup_on": "2020-03-29",
"eta": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"etd": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"change": "new"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, your first solution works with dummy data however when plugged into mine it returns the following error which I cannot seem to find a solution for; TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null at json2array(STRING)

Comment: It may be an exception thrown by your mapping function when parsing a null value. At first sight I would suggest to check data source for missing fields or to handle the null values in your js json2array function.